# Problema al ejecutar un .exe con pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Bunas, les comento mi problema, al estar trabajando con el paquete **anaconda3-4.2.0 x86** para windows 10 x64 podia generar mi programa .exe y funcionaba correctamente. Luego tuve que formatear mi PC por unos problemas y le instale la misma version de widows 10 x64, pero con anaconda **anaconda3-5.0.0 x86** ya el mismo script construido por **pyinstaller** no ejecutaba. Pasando a la antigua version de anaconda, osea la **4.2.0**, tampoco vuele a funcionar el .exe generado por **pyinstaller**.

Luego al generar un programa de prueba llamando a los mismos paquetes que utiliza mi programa, el que genera el problema es **pyqt5**, siendo que este funcionaba **correctamente** en la misma version **4.2.0 x86**.

A continuacion vemos el mensaje de error que aparece al intentar ejecutar el programa.

> "
> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt >platform plugin "windows"
> in "".
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

La salida de pyinstaller es la siguiente:

> 500 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3
>
> 500 INFO: Python: 3.5.2
>
> 500 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.10586-SP0

Estos son los warning que genera pyinstaller:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora analizando los **.dll** del .exe que **funciona** vs el .exe que **no funciona** con el comando:

> pyi-bindepend

Veo que el archivo que **funciona** tiene los siguientes paquetes:

> WS2_32.dll
>
> user32.dll
>
> kernel32.dll
>
> msvcrt.dll

Mientras el **no funciona** genera solo lo siguiente:

> WS2_32.dll
>
> kernel32.dll

Que deberia hacer para poder solucionar mi problema, ya que la version que funciona tiene errores en el codigo.

Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ami me paso algo similar hace mucho tiempo, toca buscar el problema al compilar las dll de plugins pyqt.
pero te recomiendo que uses pyqt4 que tiene mayor compatibilidad pyinstaller.
valida que todas las dependendencia esten instaladas
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2573

Comment: gracias por la infomacion, tuve que volver a PyQt4 para solucionar el problema.